# How to add new nodes in between two existing nodes

Tags: matlab, graph, nodes

I have the following `Graph` created in MATLAB

```
function dummyGraph()
tail = [1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 8 9 10 10 12 13 14 15];
head = [2 3 4 5 6 7 12 8 9 10 15 11 13 14 15 16];
Graph = graph(tail,head)
plot(Graph)
NodeNumber = 1:16
Neighbor={};
for NodeIdx =NodeNumber
    Neighbor{NodeIdx} = neighbors(Graph,NodeIdx);
end
end
```

I want to add nodes in between two consecutive nodes.

I'm trying the following approach

1.Obtain the neighbor nodes of all the nodes present in `Graph`.
2. Add four new nodes between two consecutive neighbors.

I could implement the first step in the code. I couldn't find MATLAB commands for adding nodes between existing nodes.
A command `addnode(G,nodeIDs)` is given in MATLAB documentation. But, I am not sure how to make use of this command to implement for my case.

I would like to ask for suggestions on how to proceed

Comment: I want to clarify the meaning of adding four new nodes in between two consecutive neighbors. Does it mean that, for example, adding node 17, 18, 19, and 20 in between node 1 and 2. Adding node 21, 22, 23, and 24 in between node 2 an 3 and so on?

Comment: @BanghuaZhao You are absolutely right. I want to proceed in the same way.I am not really particular about doing this task in MATLAB. Is there any other platform(python?) in which this can be achieved?

Comment: I see. What about node number that is not consecutive but connected? For example, node 6 and 12, they are connected but the number is not consecutive.

Comment: @BanghuaZhao I would like to add 4 new nodes between 6 and 12 too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution ,

```
function AddNodes()
tail = [1 2];
head = [2 3];
Graph = graph(tail,head)
NVertex = size(Graph.Nodes);
NVertex = NVertex(1);

%% Name Nodes

NNode = string(1:NVertex)';
Graph.Nodes.Name = cellstr(NNode);


%% Adding nodes
GraphEdges = table2cell(Graph.Edges(:,1));
NEdges = size(GraphEdges);
NEdges = NEdges(1);
Source=[];
Sink =[];
for edge = 1:NEdges
    Graph  = addnode(Graph,4);
    source = GraphEdges{edge}(1);
    sink = GraphEdges{edge}(2);
    Graph  = rmedge(Graph,source,sink); 
    Add4Musk = Graph.Nodes.Name(end-3:end);
    TobeAdded  = vertcat(source,Add4Musk,sink);
    for node = 1:length(TobeAdded)-1
        source = TobeAdded(node);
        sink = TobeAdded(node+1);
        Graph = addedge(Graph,source,sink);
    end 
end

%% Plot graph
plot(Graph,'Layout','subspace3')
```

I would be happy to know if there are alternate ways of doing this task.